# Divergent Mercador Series of Matrix Logarithm

Tags: matrices

The logarithm of a matrix
$$ \ln(I+A)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k+1}\over k}A^k$$

converges when ${\rho}(A)<1$

Suppose $n>{\rho}(A)>1$.

Can one use the following transformation
$$I+A=(1-n)I + nI + A = (1-n)I +n(I+{A\over n})$$
and then
$$\ln(n(I+{A\over n}))+\ln(I+e^{\ln((1-n)I)-\ln(n(I+{A\over n}))})$$
to obtain
$$\ln(nI)+\ln(I+{A\over n}) + \ln(I+e^{\ln((1-n)I)-\ln(n(I+{A\over n}))})$$
as the second term now converges?

How can the third term be evaluated?

Comment: Something is wrong with the first line of your transformation. You got $\frac{1}{n}{\rm I} + A = n \left( {\rm I} + \frac{1}{n}A \right)$. Note the factor before ${\rm I}$.

Comment: @VedranŠego, thank you.

Comment: You cannot just replace $n$ with $n^{-1}$. Now your factor before $A$ is wrong.

Comment: @VedranŠego, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't $n \left( I + \frac{1}{n}A \right)$, for which you need a logarithm in the exponent in the third term, have even bigger eigenvalues, hence defeating the purpose of all this?

Since I'm not that familiar with matrix functions, I'll just direct you to the following paper: Al-Mohy, Higham, "[Improved Inverse Scaling and Squaring Algorithms for the Matrix Logarithm](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1851/)". The main idea is to use matrix square root to get the eigenvalues of $A^{1/2^s}$ closer to one. I've seen some talks on the subject and the results seem pretty good.

Comment: What matters is that the spectral radius of ${A\over n}$ decreases so that we arrive at $I{\ln n}+{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\over {n^k \times k}}A^k}$.

In this case the convergence radius should become n, not 1, as far as I understand.
Thank you for the paper.

Comment: I understand your idea, but you still have $$\ln \left( n \left( I + \frac{1}{n}A \right) \right).$$ I doubt that Al-Mohy and Higham would resort to square root if a simple division would solve this.

Comment: Yes, that the power series of $\ln(I+e^{\ln((1-n)I)-\ln(n(I+{A\over n}))})$ should diverge and $Y=e^{\ln((1-n)I)-\ln(n(I+{A\over n}))})$ should have $\rho(Y)>1$ is clear. If the trace of the third term could be evaluated. The paper you referred to is really helpful.